# Too many simultaneous requests with Akka and futures

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, akka, future

My scenario is something like this.

1. I have a vector consisting of a large number of reports that needs to be sent using a rest api call.
2. I am using Futures.traverse(the vector mentioned in 1)
3. Since the vector is too huge, it is failing with max open requests exceeded.

One initial solution that I could think of is to increase the max-open-requests setting. But the problem here is I am not aware of the number of reports that needs to be sent beforehand.

Can someone please suggest an alternative solution like limiting the parallelism that is taking place through Futures.traverse

Comment: how are you making the REST calls?  Can you share some code?

Answer (score 3):

Since you tag this question with `akka`, I'm assuming that you are using akka-http for the calls. You could use akka-streams to make the requests in batch so to avoid to overflow your connections, something like:

```
Source(reportsVector)
  .grouped(safeValue)
  .mapAsync(1)(reps => Future.traverse(reps)(x => ...)) //do your stuff
  .mapConcat(identity)
  .runWith(Sink.seq)
```

The example will execute `safeValue` concurrent calls at a time and collect all the results into a collection that will be returned when the entire stream is done. You can also play with other operators like `sliding` and `splitWhen` to make it better for your use case, you can tune the `safeValue` and the `mapAsync` concurrency values as well. Notice that the source of this stream is a known vector (`reportsVector`) but it could be an unknown finite stream of reports as well.